# Why was this question removed

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Why was this question removed: [jQuery link toggle not hiding divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884361/jquery-link-toggle-not-hiding-the-rest-divs/)

Agreed the question doesn't satisfy the SSCCE requirement, is that sufficient ground for a direct deletion?

Comment: My typical +1 for asking constructively.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The post was flagged as spam. I agreed. The link that supposedly went to a code sample actually went to a computer repair shop's website.

Thinking about it some more, it's possible that there was just a non-native speaker/language barrier issue and what the OP meant was that the code he was working on was in use at the target website. That would make it not-spam, but still not very useful. Looking again now.

---

Okay, I've undeleted it. I still can't make much sense of it, but considering the context I'm willing to give it the benefit of the doubt on being not-spam, and you seem to have figured out what the OP wanted.

Comment: Any reason you left the link to the computer repair site?  I've since edited it out, but if you think it belongs...

Comment: @AdamRackis even if it were the target website, it shouldn't be there right? Doesn't SO discourage links to websites and prefer code samples instead so that the question can still be relevant and not depend on an external link?

Comment: @aug - sure, but even worse is that the link in question *does* seem to be bonafide **spam**, which is why I wasn't sure why it was left alone.

Comment: @AdamRackis After I went back, I didn't get the sense that the link to the repair site was there for promotional purposes; rather, it seemed to have to do with the code. I've seen similar not-great-but-not-abusive links be left in posts in the past, so I figured I'd just be consistent (after removing the obfuscation).

Comment: Ahhh - sorry.  I'm sure you were right, @pops.  That some people would test code by *first* deploying it to an actual website honestly never occurred to me.

Comment: Mostly a note for myself: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)